# XCode - execute code when block is finished

Tags: ios, ios7, block

So I'm trying to log-in/signup users using ACAccountStore. This happens using a view controller that presented modally. It works just fine that way, however, when I dismiss the view controller, the underlying/presenting view controller is still a black window. I assume this happens, because I do not wait for the completion block to finish.

So my question: How do I wait for the completion block to finish before calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`?

```
-(void)loginWithTwitter{

ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted) {
         //do something -> call function to handle the data and dismiss the modal controller.
     }
     else{
        //fail and put our error message.
     }  
 }];
}
```

Comment: why can't you just put it after the else? Barring that why don't you use the perform selector after delay if you need some kind of delay.  It isn't pretty but C'est la vie.

Answer (score 2):

Completion block is that thing that will be executed **after** the main process (access to accounts request in this case) is finished. So you can put `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` in it.

Another thing: it is bad to have reference to `self` in block because of retain cycles. You would modify your code to look like this:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
        ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

__weak UIViewController *weakSelf = self;
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if (granted) {
        //do something -> call function to handle the data and dismiss the modal controller.
    }
    else {
        //fail and put our error message.
    }

}];
```

Comment: hmm. this "works" - but does not get rid of the problem. which leads me to believe that the brief "black screen" before the appearance of the presenting view controller has nothing to to with the block.

Comment: I think that there is an issue in underlying view controller. What do you expect instead of black screen?

Comment: well - pretty much the "regular" disMissViewControllerAnimated behavior. ModalView scrolls down, underlying screen is revealed. But yeah, it seems like it's actually a problem with the underlying controller.